# How to update pandas dataframe columns based on another dataframe faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the below code to update a dataframe based on another one. However, it is dramatically slow. I am looking for a solution.

```
for inx, row in df1.iterrows():
    dfTmp = df2.loc[df2['KANR'].astype(str) == row['KANR']]
    if dfTmp.empty:
        continue

    if dfTmp.loc[dfTmp['STATUS'] == "F5"].empty is False:
        timestamp = "%s %s" % (dfTmp.loc[dfTmp['STATUS'].astype(str) == "F5"].iloc[0, ]["Date"],
                               dfTmp.loc[dfTmp['STATUS'].astype(str) == "F5"].iloc[0, ]["Time"])
        df1.set_value(inx, 'F5', timestamp)
```

Comment: Its usually easier if you provide your df.head() and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`, which is optimized for speed and will be much faster for this kind of match task, something like this, assuming you don't have duplicated date time for each `KANR`:

```
df2['F5'] = df2['Date'].astype(str) + " " + df2['Time'].astype(str)
to_join = df2.loc[df2['STATUS'].astype(str) == 'F5', ['F5', 'KANR']].groupby('KANR').head(1)
df1.merge(to_join, how='left', on = 'KANR')
```